# more intuitive and explicit explanation of $f^{-1}[\bigcap B_i]=\bigcap f^{-1}[B_i]$ and $f^{-1}[B']=(f^{-1}[B])'$ for beginner?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Given a surjective function $f:X \to Y$ and an indexed subsets collection $\{B_i\}$ of the codomain  $Y$, then:

$$f^{-1}[\bigcap B_i]=\bigcap f^{-1}[B_i]$$
$$f^{-1}[B_i']=(f^{-1}[B_i])'$$

By writing both equations above into the form of '$\forall$ and $\exists$' I get
$$\{x:\ (\exists y)(\forall i)\ ([y \in B_i]\wedge[\langle y,x \rangle \in f^{-1}])\}=\{x:\ (\forall i)(\exists y)\ ([y \in B_i]\wedge[\langle y,x \rangle \in f^{-1}])\}$$
$$\{x:\ (\exists y)\ ([y \notin B_i]\wedge[\langle y,x \rangle \in f^{-1}])\}=\{x:\ (\exists y)\ ([y \in B_i]\wedge[\langle y,k \rangle \in f^{-1}]\wedge[x \in \text{range }f^{-1}]\wedge[k \cap x= \varnothing])\}$$

The above two forms don't seem to represent the equations explicit enough, especially for the first one because $(\exists y)(\forall i)$ and $(\forall i)(\exists y)$ carry different meaning

---

So I came up with a somewhat more explicit explanation as follow:

**[Step 1]:** Because $f:X \to Y$ is a surjective function, each unique $y \in Y$ can be seen as an unique index for a certain subset of $X$. That is to say if I present $X$ and $Y$ as the following form
$$\begin{cases}X=\{x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n\}\\Y=\{y_1,y_2,\dots,y_m\}\\\text{where }m \le n\end{cases}$$
then $f^{-1}(y_k)=A_k$ is a subset of $X$, and for every unique $y_k$ there is an unique $A_k$, and also every two different $A_k$ are disjoint, which means
$$\begin{cases}\bigcup A_k=f^{-1}(y_1) \cup f^{-1}(y_2) \cup \dots \cup f^{-1}(y_m)\\\bigcup A_k=X\\A_k\text{ fibers set X}\end{cases}$$
This is why each $y_k$ can be seen as an unique index for $X$'s subset $A_k$. Because if I have, for example $y_1$, then i can identify a certain portion of $X$ through the transformation $f^{-1}(y_1)$, and this portion $A_1$ cannot be identified by other $y_k\ (y_2,y_3,\dots,y_m)$.

**[Step 2]:** After clarifying that $Y$ is an index set of $X$, I can then claim:

> Naturally, the [intersection of the “index (Y)”] has the same effect as  the [intersection of “indexed (X)”], thus}$$f^{-1}[\bigcap B_i]=\bigcap f^{-1}[B_i]$$

> And similarly, the [complement of the “index (Y)”] has the same effect as the [complement of “indexed (X)”], thus}$$f^{-1}[B_i']=(f^{-1}[B_i])'$$

---

But the above explanation doesn't seem to be intuitive enough, so what is the more intuitive and explicit explanation of the first two equations, for someone who has just started learning set theory like me?

Comment: If you want to show that sets $V$ and $W$ are equal, a common approach is to show that $V \subset W$ and also that $W \subset V$. Let's try to show that $\cap f^{-1}(B_i) \subset f^{-1}(\cap B_i)$. Suppose that $x \in \cap f^{-1}(B_i)$. What do we know about $x$? Can we conclude that $f(x) \in \cap B_i$ ?

Comment: @littleO, I think it can be done if I can prove $f(f^{-1}[B])=B$ when $f$ is surjective, which might be shown by the following process, suppose:
$$B_i\xrightarrow{f^{-1}}X_i\xrightarrow{f}Y_i$$
Then the operation $f^{-1}$ enlarges the set $B_i$ into $X_i$, and the operation $f$ narrows the set $X_i$ into $Y_i$.

Comment: @littleO, But here is the issue: I want to say because $f$ is surjective, the scale of enlarging and narraowing are the same, so $B_i=Y_i$ but I found I can't since if I reverse the order of operation
$$X_i\xrightarrow{f}Y_i\xrightarrow{f^{-1}}C_i$$
then obviously $X_i \subseteq C_i$ and in this case the scale of enlarging is greater than narrowing

Comment: Let’s just follow our nose: $x \in \cap f^{-1}(B_i) \implies x \in f^{-1}(B_i) \text{ for all } i \implies f(x) \in B_i \text{ for all } i \implies f(x) \in \cap B_i \implies x \in f^{-1}(\cap B_i)$.

Comment: @littleO, but if I want to say $(\forall i)(x \in f^{-1}[B_i]) \implies (\forall i)(f(x) \in B_i)$, isn't it necessary for me to show $(\forall i)(f(f^{-1}[B_i])=B_i)$ ?

Comment: No, $f^{-1}(B_i)$ is by definition $\{ x \in X \mid f(x) \in B_i \}$. So if $x \in f^{-1}(B_i)$, then by definition $f(x) \in B_i$.

Comment: To add on to littleO's answer, what you thought should be shown isn't even correct: generally $f(f^{-1}[B]) \subseteq B$, with equality if and only if $f$ is surjective. It's always worth sanity-checking a conjecture!

Comment: @William, I have always assumed $f$ is surjective from the start if you check the first sentence of the question. (I'm just adding this comment so I won't get confused next time I review this post.) But thanks for the advice :D

Comment: @littleO, Ah I see, so for $f^{-1}[B_i']=(f^{-1}[B_i])'$, similarly I can have 
$$x\in f^{-1}[B_i'] \iff f(x) \in B_i' \iff (f(x))' \in B_i \iff f(x') \in B_i \iff x' \in f^{-1}[B_i] \iff x \in (f^{-1}[B_i])'$$

Comment: My above comment is wrong. Because $[f(x) \in B_i'] \nLeftrightarrow [(f(x))' \in B_i]$, and also $[(f(x))' \in B_i] \nLeftrightarrow [f(x') \in B_i]$,in general

$$\text{$(f(x))' \subseteq f(x')$ if and only if $f$ is surjective, and $(f(x))' = f(x')$ if and only if $f$ is bijective.}$$

The correct steps for $f^{-1}[B_i']=(f^{-1}[B_i])'$ is
$$x\in f^{-1}[B_i'] \iff f(x) \in B_i' \iff f(x) \notin B_i \iff x \notin f^{-1}[B_i] \iff x \in (f^{-1}[B_i])'$$

Comment: What do these primes mean? What is the meaning of $x’$?

Comment: @littleO, $x'$ means the complement of $x$, I got this notation from Loomis and Sternberg's <Advanced Calculus>

Comment: But when you write for example “$f(x’) \in B_i$”, $x$ is not a set is it? What do you mean by the complement of something that is not a set?

Comment: @littleO, you are right, thats another mistake I made, thanks for the clarification

Comment: So to correct my mistake pointed out by littleO above, the part I should fix is to say
$$\text{for a subset $M \subset X$:}\\\text{$(f(M))' \subseteq f(M')$ if and only if $f$ is surjective,}\\\text{and $(f(M))' = f(M')$ if and only if $f$ is bijective.}$$
The steps 
$$x\in f^{-1}[B_i'] \iff f(x) \in B_i' \iff f(x) \notin B_i \iff x \notin f^{-1}[B_i] \iff x \in (f^{-1}[B_i])'$$
are still correct because I didn't use any problematic notations such as $x'$